# accessing grails app from external computer

Tags: grails, networking, deployment, virtual-machine

I have Grails web services app running on a Linux VM.

From within the VM, I can use POSTMAN to hit the login service and get credentials.

From outside the VM, I get "This seems to be like an error connecting to http://100.100.100.100:8080/myservice/login. The response status was 0."

I started grails with these paramters:
grails -Dserver.host=xx.xx.xx.xx -Dserver.port=8080 dev run-app

It is a VirtualBox VM and the network is setup to be Bridged.

Any one know how to make my services accessible to other machines?

thanks

Comment: Got it.  In CentOS, you have to disable (or correctly configure)  ip_tables and firewalld.

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't use `grails run-app` to start a Grails app in anything other than a development environment